# Dropbox how to download more than 10k files

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working on a project where my client has uploaded files on dropbox. He has uploaded ~39k articles. The problem is when I try to download them from dropbox, I get an error "The zip file is too large". I've been trying to download that data somehow but haven't been able to download it yet.
Any ideas how to download such enormous number of files from dropbox ?